# Why do newly added or edited contacts float to the top of my iPhone's contact list?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

Any newly added contacts, or contacts that have been edited are immediately sorted to the top of my contacts list on my iPhone 4 running iOS 5.0.1 using iCloud. The iPhone has not been jailbroken, or tampered with in any way. I'm not even able to use the quick select letters on the right that are above the letter R (See Example Photograph). I've deleted the contacts, and have re-entered them multiple times. I have even restored the iPhone 4 to see if that would fix the issue, and have even tried using an iPhone 3GS to test on with no differing results. Needless to say that this issue is occurring across the board, which makes me think it may be a setting that I'm unable to find. Has anyone else come across this issue? Does anyone know of a solution? Thanks a lot in advance!

**Example Photograph**:

[image]

Comment: Do you sync your contacts with any other service (Exchange, Gmail etc)?

Comment: Negative. Just iCloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears something has become corrupt in your contacts backup.

When you say you've deleted contacts and re-entered them, do you mean you have restored them from backup, or manually created new ones?

If the latter, you can try rebuilding your contacts on a desktop and then re-syncing them. Are you using a Mac or PC?

Comment: Manually created new ones. It seems like it has been corrupted, and I'll have to go through and edit each contact for them to "restore" to a situation the contacts/phone applications like. I was hoping for an easier solution, but this seems to be the only way to go. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can try exporting all your contacts to a .csv file on the desktop, deleting them all from the app, then re-importing the .csv file. This should restore all your contact. You can then sync, and hopefully resolve your issue.